# XOR operation in Cython within a nogil context for hashing a vector with a hex

Tags: c++, cython, xor

I am trying to define a hash for a sorted vector of type `size_t`. As part of the solution, I use an XOR operation.

```
cdef size_t vector_hash(const vector[size_t]& v) noexcept nogil:
    """Hash a vector of size_t."""
    cdef size_t seed = v.size()
    cdef size_t i, hash_val
    for i in v:
        seed = seed ^ (i + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2))
    hash_val = seed
    return hash_val
```

However, I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef size_t vector_hash(const vector[size_t]& v) noexcept nogil:
    """Hash a vector of size_t."""
    cdef size_t seed = v.size()
    cdef size_t i, hash_val
    for i in v:
        seed = seed ^ (i + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2))
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/tree/_utils.pyx:155:20: Coercion from Python not allowed without the GIL
```

My questions are:

1. Why can't you use the XOR in a nogil context here?
2. What is a way to implement XOR in a nogil context then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The constant `0x9e3779b9` is treated as a python integer, we should cast it to `size_t`: `<size_t>0x9e3779b9`
2. Cython cannot generate the right code for the loop `for i in v` when `v` is `const vector[size_t]&`, Cython will produce a non-const interator which result in a compiling error. We can drop the const qualifier: `size_t vector_hash(vector[size_t]& v)` or use an alternative loop method:

```
    for i in range(v.size()):
        seed = seed ^ (v[i] + <size_t>0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2))
```